# Implementing custom header for retrofit and i get No Retrofit annotation found, error

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

this below code is calling webservice which i want to implementing that with `Retrofit` on Android, but i get this error:

```
No Retrofit annotation found
```

calling `Web Service` with `CURL`:

```
curl -H "X-Auth-Token: 9HqLlyZOugoStsXCUfD_0YdwnNnunAJF8V47U3QHXSq" \
     -H "X-User-Id: aobEdbYhXfu5hkeqG" \
     http://localhost:3000/api/v1/channels.list
```

i wrote this interface like with above code:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Header;
public interface RocketRestfulService {
    @GET("/api/v1/channels.list")
    Call<List<ChannelsList>> getChannelsList(
            @Header("X-Auth-Token") String AuthToken,
            @Header("X-User-Id") String UserId,
            ChannelsList channelsList);
}
```

and i'm calling this rest `Web Service` by this code:

```
ChannelsList channelsList = new ChannelsList();
Call<List<ChannelsList>> call = rocketRestfulService.getChannelsList(
        "HNv1VtMiyUky2RkXWUydyj4f2bfciQ6DzVQgKULSwfe",
        "Wz9ex2N2z9zzJWdzD",
        channelsList);
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ChannelsList>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<ChannelsList>> call, final Response<List<ChannelsList>> response) {
        Log.e("contentLength ", response.code() + "");
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<ChannelsList>> call, Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

whats problem of my code that i can't call and i get error?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `@Body` annotation. And since you have to send a body, you must create a `POST` to your API. If is not a `POST`, you must find how to send `ChannelsList` in order to be a `GET` request because is depending your server implementation.

```
@POST("/api/v1/channels.list")
Call<List<ChannelsList>> getChannelsList(
        @Header("X-Auth-Token") String AuthToken,
        @Header("X-User-Id") String UserId,
        @Body ChannelsList channelsList);
```

Comment: i get this error `Non-body HTTP method cannot contain @Body` now

Comment: i'm trying to implementing this link on android with retrofit  `https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/rest-api/channels/list` and `HTTP Method` for this web service is `GET` i dont have any problem with some rest client on web browser

Comment: You don't have to send ChannelsList. That object is received.

Comment: i tested that, but i get null for received fields, `Call<ChannelsList> call = rocketRestfulService.getChannelsList(
                "HNv1VtMiyUky2RkXWUydyj4f2bfciQ6DzVQgKULSwfe",
                "Wz9ex2N2z9zzJWdzD");`

Comment: please see this screen shot of result [http://rupload.ir/upload/lb7iz40gm0chychkb9w.png](http://rupload.ir/upload/lb7iz40gm0chychkb9w.png)

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by this below code:

interface:

```
public interface RocketRestfulService {
    @GET("/api/v1/channels.list")
    Call<ResponseBody> getChannelsList(
            @Header("X-Auth-Token") String AuthToken,
            @Header("X-User-Id") String UserId);
}
```

call request and get response:

```
ChannelsList channelsList = new ChannelsList();
Call<ResponseBody> call = rocketRestfulService.getChannelsList(
        "HNv1VtMiyUky2RkXWUydyj4f2bfciQ6DzVQgKULSwfe",
        "Wz9ex2N2z9zzJWdzD");
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, final Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            try {
                String     jsonString = response.body().string();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                JSONArray  jsonarray  = jsonObject.getJSONArray("channels");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Err: ", t.getMessage());
    }
});
```